# ViewModel, LiveData and Transformations.map

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

New to Kotlin and Android development and related and I’m not certain what to do to apply some business logic and convert a value.  I have a List of a class and I’d like to modify one of the values in the class while leaving everything else in the class unharmed.  Once I get to the view model, I’m not certain of how to access the time value in my class to modify it.  I’d appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction.

Entity and Dao

```
import org.threeten.bp.Instant

data class ActionDetails(val time: Instant,
                     val firstName: String,
                     ... )

@Query("SELECT time, first_name as firstName...")
fun liveStatus(): LiveData<List<ActionDetails>>
```

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(private val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _actions: LiveData<List<ActionDetails>>
    val actions: LiveData<List<ActionDetails>>
        get() = _actions

    init {
        _actions = Transformations.map(repository.liveStatus()) {
            //Convert Instant value per business rules and convert to formatted string
            time -> ...

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change just 1 value. Create a new data class that represents the desired full object after the business logic transformation

e.g. from

```
data class ActionDetails(val time: Date, val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

to

```
data class DisplayItem(val time: String, val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val fullName: String)
```

Then transform your livedata from `List<ActionDetails>` to `List<DisplayItem>`. To do that you can use the `Iterable#map` function that applies a transformation to each element of the list and returns the resulting list.

```
Transformations.map(repository.liveStatus()) { list ->
    list.map { item ->
        val formattedTime = item.time.toString() // whatever you need
        val fullName = "${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}"
        DisplayItem(formattedTime, item.firstName, item.lastName, fullName)
    }
}
```

Sidenote: if it's just 1 small thing that you want to change, maybe don't use `Transformations.map` but simply format the string at the place where it's displayed, e.g. in a adapter view holder

Comment: Thank you for chiming in and the related detail—I didn’t realize I’d be building a new list.  While I’ve considered formatting the result in the data binding, I didn’t want to put all that code in the XML.  I’ll give this a spin and reevaluate my options.

Comment: In thinking about this some more, I could probably add a function to the data class to handle the formatting for this one value and call the function from the data binding in the layout.  This will keep code out of the XML file, but I’m not certain if this approach is better than a transformation.  Any opinion?

Comment: @Bink No big + for either option. Transformations run only once per update of live data afaik, which can make a difference for smooth scrolling of listviews for example where you can sometimes feel when there is post-processing of items done on the fly. But string formatting a date is pretty irrelevant so, either way should work fine